# Allow user to choose push notification time

Tags: ios, push-notification

I was wondering if there is a software to allow users to choose what time they want to receive a push notification. (It would be different for all users and there would be a default)

Comment: Are you talking about notifications managed by your own system, or notifications in general. Managing the time of distribution for a certain notification is the job of the PNS. If you don't have direct control over the notifications, you are out of luck. There is no way of delaying (remote) notifications in iOS.

Comment: You should be use API. API you can send time of push notification particular user id on API server.

Answer (score 0):

Push notifications are sent from a remote server. In order to do what you describe you'd need to set up a push notification server. It's not possible from an iOS client.

Local notifications are different. Those are scheduled and delivered locally, and you could do what you describe.

Comment: Is there a push notification service out there that already offers that or no?

Comment: I have no idea.